TikZ: \foreach and \path
I have a trouble with the code below: I don't understand why \filldraw[Silver,fill=Gold1] (P-\i) -- (P-\j); does not function. I'd like to have a watch with Silver countour and Gold1 clock faces.
Could someone help me?
Thank you in advanced
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames, x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.shapes, arrows, calc, patterns, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line width=3pt,scale=1.5]
\def\N{12}
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\N} { \coordinate (P-\i) at (\i*360/\N:2); }
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\n{\N-1} 
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\n}
   {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1}       
      \filldraw[Silver,fill=Gold1] (P-\i) -- (P-\j) ;
   } 
  \foreach \angle / \label in
    {0/3, 30/2, 60/1, 90/12, 120/11, 150/10, 180/9,
     210/8, 240/7, 270/6, 300/5, 330/4}
  {
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
    \draw (\angle:1.4cm) node{\textsf{\label}};
  }

  \foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
    \draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:1.7cm) -- (\angle:2cm);

  \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (120:0.8cm); % hour
  \draw[red] (0,0) -- (90:1cm);    % minute
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}
\end{document}


I tried running it, and those colours are not defined. The code ran when I replaced them with standard colours. Have you defined them in your main document?

No, on my Overleaf account mu code runs correctly

Oops! You're right, I didn't add the first line. Sorry about that. My suspicion that the gold isn't showing because you are just drawing line segments. The silver is showing up just fine, but filling is more so for areas.

like this? The reason it wasn't filling is because you were drawing the shape segment by segment. Instead, they all need to be in one \draw command
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames, x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.shapes, arrows, calc, patterns, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line width=3pt,scale=1.5]
\def\N{12}
  \fill[Gold1] (0*360/\N:2) \foreach \i in {1,...,\N} { -- ({(\i)*360/\N}:2)}; % added
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\N} { \coordinate (P-\i) at (\i*360/\N:2); }
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\n{\N-1} 
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\n}
   {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1}       
      \filldraw[Silver,fill=Gold1] (P-\i) -- (P-\j) ;
   } 
  \foreach \angle / \label in
    {0/3, 30/2, 60/1, 90/12, 120/11, 150/10, 180/9,
     210/8, 240/7, 270/6, 300/5, 330/4}
  {
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
    \draw (\angle:1.4cm) node{\textsf{\label}};
  }

  \foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
    \draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:1.7cm) -- (\angle:2cm);

  \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (120:0.8cm); % hour
  \draw[red] (0,0) -- (90:1cm);    % minute

  
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}
\end{document}


